# Consuming REST API from curl call

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest

How do you consume `REST API` given just a cUrl call?

I am using Clickatell's REST API. I would like to use `C#` and `HttpClient` as it is the latest and greatest way to make REST calls. I am trying to "convert" the call to be used in HttpClient. I've managed to do some of it but not sure how to do the rest.

cUrl:

```
curl -i \
-X GET \
-H "X-Version: 1" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Your Authorization Token" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-s \
https://api.clickatell.com/rest/account/balance
```

This is what I currently have:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
     httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.clickatell.com/rest/account/balance");
     httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
     httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
     httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "my_cliackatell_token");
     httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Version", "1");
}
```

I'm not sure what the following means and how do I implement them into the above code:

```
-i \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-s \
```

How do I complete the above mentioned when doing the POST?

Are these 2 settings the same thing? `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` and `-H "Accept: application/json"`

Comment: No they are quite different. Content-Type says what data you are sending (in a POST, for example), Accept tells the server what kind of data you can handle. The options are in cURL manual, -i outputs the HTTP headers also, so you don't need that. -s is silent, so no progress info etc, also don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

you can consume a get method call as follows(This is just an example)

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56851/");

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/User").Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
           // do logic
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Code" + 
            response.StatusCode + " : Message - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
```

[Refer the below link to learn more about Httpclient](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes I know, I'm looking how to implement the whole curl call into my code. This what I am actually after.